# Laravel Divide DB column on two

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

Usernames are stored in a DB in one column, how I can divide this column on first name and last names columns.

I am thinking about create a loop and run through fullname column split first name and second name by space and store them in corresponding columns. But where do I have to create this loop?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SPLIT_STR](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/) function .
Assuming each username has 2 words splitted with a space.

```
DB::query(
"INSERT INTO tables (firstname,lastname)
 SELECT SPLIT_STR(username, ' ', 1),SPLIT_STR(username, ' ', 2) FROM oldusers "
);
```